# SQL Query - Add condition in WHERE only IF another condition

Tags: sql, where-clause

I want to do something like this in a where clause

```
WHERE ( i.accountid = @accountid 
      AND CASE WHEN @IsTest IS NOT NULL THEN b.IsTest = @IsTest ELSE 1 = 1
```

But this solution does not work. Is there any solution for this. Basically I want to add a verification based on `@IsTest` value.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use simple boolean logic:

```
where  
 i.accountid = @accountid
  and 
 (@IsTest is null or b.IsTest = @Istest)
```

If you want to make your `case` solution work (just for illustrative purposes - it's not a good idea), you'd need to have the `case` return a value that you'd compare to something - T-SQL doesn't actually have a "bool type" (`bit` is just incredibly-small-integer, it doesn't have special syntax):

```
... and (case when @IsTest is not null then @IsTest else 1 end) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WHERE ( i.accountid = @accountid 
      AND b.IsTest = CASE WHEN @IsTest IS NOT NULL THEN  @IsTest ELSE 1 END)
```

or simply

```
WHERE ( i.accountid = @accountid 
      AND b.IsTest = COALESCE(@IsTest1,)
```

Comment: @IsTest is not a boolean and because of this "b.IsTest = @IsTest" does not work.

Comment: Can you try the second method I posted?

Comment: I dont want to add any other clause if IsTest is null. Thanks!